# How to check which authenticator_class is used by jupyterhub without reading jupyterhub_config file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, authenticator

I'm dynamically setting different authenticator class in jupyterhub_config file.

`jupyterhub_config.py`

> `c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = "authenticator_A"`

Now i want to check which autheticator is used in notebook cell.
How can i get this class without reading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm creating environment variable to store authenticator class name in jupyter_config.py file like below,

> `c.Spawner.environment = {"AUTHENTICATOR_CLASS": "authenticator_A"}`

And using this AUTHENTICATOR_CLASS env variable in notebook.

https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/spawner.html#jupyterhub.spawner.Spawner.environment